# Understanding the usage of a variable as an array size in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand the difference that the scoping makes:

```
//global scope
int size = 4;
int array[size]; // error: variably modified 'array' at file scope

int main(void) {
  int buff[size]; // works!
}
```

how does using a variable as array size doesn't work globally but works inside `main`? It would work if I use a macro instead.

Also, does using `const` matter for size?

Comment: in c89 ansic the size of the array must be declared as leteral (in define or just a number). this code will not compiled in c89

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858475/define-array-globally-with-variable-parameter-in-c maybe you are looking for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [declaring a variable-length array as a global variable in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360394/declaring-a-variable-length-array-as-a-global-variable-in-c)

Comment: @SomaM. Reasonable dupe.

Comment: @adam Any particular reason for referring to C89 instead of C99, C11 or C18?  OP's code works for `main(void)`, so OP much be using C99 or later.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - i'm still uncertain

Answer (score 0):

simply make it compile time integral constant expression, since array length must be specified at the compile time, with define

```
#define SIZE   6

int array[SIZE];
```

Comment: but how come it works in `main`?

Comment: please write here the compilation flags (or the compilation line you have used)

Comment: check this:
https://cplayground.com/?p=bird-echidna-sandpiper